# confusion on the application of uniform boundedness principle: does $u_k\to u$ weakly imply that $u_k$ is uniformly bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be reflexive space. Let $u_k\to u$ weakly. That means for every $\phi\in X^*$, we have $\phi(u_k)\to \phi(u)$. This, and the reflexivity imply that $u_k\to u$ point-wise in $X^{**}$. By uniform boundedness principle, we indeed have that $u_k$ is bounded uniformly in $X^{**}$. By isometry of $X$ and $X^{**}$, $u_k$ is bounded uniformly in $X$.

However it seems intuitively clear that weak convergence directly implies uniform boundedness. Maybe it holds only on convergence in norm topology. I might be wrong.

Could anyone help me clarify this?

Comment: Weak convergence means that $u_k\to u$ pointwise on $X^*,$ as the elements of $X$ are treated as functionals on $X^*.$ As $X^*$ is complete the sequence $u_k$ is bounded. No reflexivity is needed.

Comment: Oh, I see where I was confused. Do you mean $u_k\to u$ point-wise on $X^{**}$ since we treat them as elements in $X^{**}$? edit: sorry I think it now makes sense to say point-wise on $X^*$ since it's evaluated on it. Thanks!

Comment: can we say that this is in a way the most "sparse" topology that we can extract subsequence on?